# Вопрос по постраничной навигации

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, pagination

Имеется код:

```
<?php  
};  
?>

         <?php  
         $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM news";  
         $rs_result = mysql_query($sql);  
         $row = mysql_fetch_row($rs_result);  
         $total_records = $row[0];
         $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $limit);  
         $pagLink = "<nav><ul class='pagination'>";  
         for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  
         $pagLink .= "<li><a href='news.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";  
};  
         echo $pagLink . "</ul></nav>";  
         ?>
```

Вопрос: Как добавить к навигации класс "active"?

Comment: брать номер страницы из url и сравнивать с $i и если они равны то выводить класс "active"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такая проверка будет более правильной, так как если параметр page не передается, то страница должна выводиться все равно первая.

```
$page = ((int)$_GET['page'] > 0) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
if ($page == $i) echo 'class="active"';
```

Answer (score 0):

Как видно из структуры урла - номер страницы хранится в переменной `page`:

```
if ($i == $_GET['page']) echo 'class="active"';
```